How to configure AWS::SNS::Topic ArchivePolicy?
Using CloudFormation, I'm trying to deploy an SNS topic with an ArchivePolicy of 90 days. From the AWS docs, this Property is "Type: Json" but I can find no reference to its structure. I did find this recent AWS article, that hints at the structure containing a single key named "MessageRetentionPeriod" and its value an integer in days.
Here is my CloudFormation template
AWSTemplateFormatVersion : '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Description: SNS topic for my application

Resources:
  # --------------- SNS --------------- #
  MyTopic:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties:
      TopicName: MyTopic
      ArchivePolicy:
        MessageRetentionPeriod: 90

When I try to deploy using the AWS SAM CLI, I receive the following error:
Resource handler returned      
message: "Invalid parameter:   
Attributes Reason: Unknown     
attribute ArchivePolicy        
(Service: Sns, Status Code:    
400, Request ID: xxxxxxxx-     
xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)"  
(RequestToken: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-  
xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx,        
HandlerErrorCode:              
GeneralServiceException)

So how to configure an SNS topic with the ArchivePolicy using a CloudFormation template?

From my understanding of the announcement post, this is only supported on FIFO topics and you're not setting FifoTopic: true in your example.

It looks like you're right - this is only available on FIFO Topics. Cheers
